# create php file from user input

Tags: php

I need to create `php` file from user input using following code to create php file

```
<?php
    $my_file = 'newfile.php';
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); 
?>
```

above code creates new php file but i need to create file with some content

example I have two input

```
<input type="file" name="cover">
<input type="text" name="body">
```

php file should contain above input

Comment: What did you try and where did you fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write to file using `fwrite`. Try the following code.

```
fwrite($handle, 'Content form input 1');
fwrite($handle, 'content from input 2');
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
another example for create file:
  i have a folder names files where saved my creating my files and file ext = .txt 
 $fh = fopen("$files/{$id}.txt","w");
  fwrite($fh,$_POST['description']);//description is my field name where write something and send via post method
   fcolse($fh)
```

Comment: Add some description to your code. It will help users better than just some piece of code.